# Stuck on the integral $\int_0^{\infty}\frac{2+7\mathrm{cos}(x^\pi-e)-7\mathrm{sin}(1+x^8)}{1+x^2} \mathrm{d}x$

Tags: calculus, integration, improper-integrals

Does anyone have any advice on how to evaluate the following integral?

$$\int_0^{\infty}\frac{2+7\mathrm{cos}(x^\pi-e)-7\mathrm{sin}(1+x^8)}{1+x^2} \mathrm{d}x$$

It looks like it converges, but I have no idea where to even begin evaluating it. Any tips would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: In one word: WHY?

Comment: What evidence do you have that this is evaluatable in any form but approximately?

Comment: My best guess would be to use complex variable methods. Have you looked into that?

Comment: Using trig identities, your integral reduces to determining integrals of the form $\int_0^\infty \cos(x^p)/(1+x^2) dx$ and $\int_0^\infty \sin(x^p)/(1+x^2) dx$. These seem like reasonable integrals to try to compute, perhaps someone has done them before.

Comment: I started solving this insane integral. To solve the partial trigonometric integrals, I convert the common denominator into a geometric series, and the partial integrals can be solved. The results can be only be expressed in a Hypergeometric Function.

Comment: Defining an extended cossecant Mittag-Leffler function, as $E_{a,b} (z)= \sum {{{z^n} csc(1-a*n-b)} \over \Gamma(a*n+b)}$, The partial integrals can be solved.

Comment: Then, $ \int_{0}^{\infty}$ ${cos(x^p) \over (1+x^2)} dx = \pi cos (\pi / 2 p) E_{{p-1} \over p,-2 \over p} (1)$ , and $\int_0^\infty sin(x^p) / (1+x^2) dx = \pi sin (\pi / 2 p) E_{{p-1} \over 2, -2 \over p} (1)$.

Answer (score 3):

Since the integrand is bounded above and below by:
$$ \frac{16}{x^2+1} > f(x) > \frac{-14}{x^2+1}$$
Both which converge (t0 $8\pi$ and $-7\pi$ respectively), the integral converges to some value in between. Other than that, I'd bet against a closed form solution.

Answer (score 2):

Not a fully answer, but hopefully useful information: for the cosine part, I noticed that $$\begin{aligned}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}I(a)&=\int_0^\infty\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}\frac{\cos\left(x^\pi-a\right)}{1+x^2}\,dx\\
& = -\int_0^\infty \frac{\cos\left(x^\pi-a\right)}{1+x^2}\,dx\\
&=-I(a)\\\end{aligned}$$ and, then, our integral $I(e)$ $$I(e)=K\sin(e)$$ for some constant $K.$ One way to find $K$ is evaluating $I(\pi/2)$ or another convenient value. [Numerical evidence](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=approximate+%28%5Cint_0%5E%5Cinfty+%5Cfrac%7B%5Ccos%28x%5E%5Cpi-e%29%7D%7B1%2Bx%5E2%7Ddx%29%2F%28sin%28e%29%28cos%281%29%2B4%29%2F%28Pi%2B1%2F3%29%29) suggests $K=-{\cos(1)+4\over \pi+1/3}$, but I don't know whether Wolfram is pointing a rational value or giving up calculations. I'd like someone to test it in a more powerful environment.